# Android Studio Gradle 4.1 update to Give error on Project Regard APT

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apt

Android Studio `Gradle 4.1` update  to Give error on Project Regard `APT` file

I Use apt in `gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.4-rc2'
```

Any idea which `depedancy` are replace with those file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove plugin and use like below

```
implementation 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.4-rc2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle plugin 3.0.0 and up the apt is no longer supported. use in-built annotation processor.

```
dependencies {
compileOnly 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.4-rc2'
}
```

Remove the line.

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

From official doc. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#annotationProcessor_config